# Can't identify fitting in residential well water service line

Tags: plumbing, well, fitting

I am replacing some plumbing while replacing a pressure tank in a residential well system. After the water enters the residence from the well pump, after the first shut-off, the following fitting appears:

[image]

I am trying to simplify the setup and see if this is a fitting that I can ignore while replumbing.

Comment: That is an air valve(tire valve), usually to add air to a pressure tank.  Without a bigger picture showing more, it might be to blow water out of the lines for winter.

Comment: Thanks, doesnt sound important either way so im going to ignore